# Trigger in sybase insert in another database

Tags: sybase

is there something wrong with this trigger ? It suppose to insert a datefield on a table in another database. Can anyone give me a hand ? thanks

```
ALTER TRIGGER "tri_ins" AFTER INSERT
ORDER 1 ON "DBA"."ta_1"
/* REFERENCING NEW AS new_name */
FOR EACH STATEMENT /* WHEN( search_condition ) */
BEGIN
    this i do and don't work


    INSERT INTO [t2].dbo.ta_2 
              (f_id, f_name)
        SELECT f_id, f_name
        FROM   inserted;
END
```

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version?  what doesn't work ... the `alter trigger` command fails/errors-out ... or the trigger fires but a row is not inserted into the `[t2].dbo.ta_2` table?

Comment: thank you ,SQLAnywhere data v16 .this is the error message
the row could not be inserted .
table 't_2' not found